# Setting canvas position inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm having some issues positioning a canvas with javascript.
The flow of my operation is the following:

1. An Ajax request is sent to the server
2. On response received I get my data from a JSON value and call a function on those data
3. The function operates with `simpleheat` in order to draw an heatmap on the canvas, overlayed to the original image.

Here's the `HTML`

```
<div id="rightPanel" class="col-md-9">
    <img id="worldMap" width="800" height="600" />
    <canvas class="coveringCanvas" id="heatmap" />
</div>
```

The class `coveringCanvas` is

```
    .coveringCanvas {
    position: absolute;
}
```

My AJAX request:

```
function OnUpdateClick() {
    begin = beginDate.GetDate().toLocaleString("it-IT");
    end = endDate.GetDate().toLocaleString("it-IT");
    if (begin == null || end == null) {
        alert("Immettere delle date!")
    } else {
        $.post("/Heatmap/getHeatmap",
            { beginDate: begin, endDate: end },
            function (data) {
                map = data["mapImage"];
                var img = document.getElementById('worldMap');
                img.src = arrayBufferDataUri(map);
                positions = data["positions"];
                drawPoints(positions);
            });
    }
```

and the `DrawPoints` function:

```
 function drawPoints(data) {
    var img = document.getElementById('worldMap');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('heatmap');
    console.log("Image x: " + img.x)
    console.log("Image y: " + img.y)
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.style.left = img.x + "px";
    canvas.style.top = img.y + "px";
    simpleheat('heatmap').data(data).radius(30,25).draw();
}
```

Now, setting `height` and `width` for my `canvas` is no problem.

Setting `top` and `left` is.

If I repeat the same instructions from the `javascript` console in my browser (Firefox Quantum), the positioning works flawlessly.

If I log the `img.x` and `img.y` values they are correct in the function too, the problem seems to be the assignment to `canvas`.

What can it be?

Comment: Your current code is not using your values. Should that read `canvas.style.left = img.x + "px";` ?

Comment: yes I pasted an olter version by mistake, I've corrected it

Comment: Is it still not working even when setting position to absolute as @Vini suggested?

Comment: I can't try in this exact moment, I will in a few minutes!

Comment: Ok, also when you changed your code to the hard coded `15px` was it positioning it to 15px correctly?

Comment: Yes, as far as I remember lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could set the [Style position Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_position.asp) inside the function prior to left and top?

Example:

```
 function drawPoints(data) {
    var img = document.getElementById('worldMap');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('heatmap');
    console.log("Image x: " + img.x)
    console.log("Image y: " + img.y)
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.style.position = 'absolute';  // Right Here!
    canvas.style.left = "15px";
    canvas.style.top = "15px";
    simpleheat('heatmap').data(data).radius(30,25).draw();
}
```

Comment: There was an error since I pasted an old version of the code by mistake. Check the new drawPoints, where I use img.x and img.y for top and left of the canvas and tell me if your answer remains the same (it should). By the way I'm going to try shortly and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: img.x & img.y are getting values. NOT setting them. For the record and without knowing your next intentions of course. :)